# How can I read a csv file from my library in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm new to Qualtrics, HTML, and Javascript, so feel free to let me know if what I'm asking for is impossible.

I'm trying to use Qualtrics to gather some data that relates applicant test scores and schools that the same applicants were admitted to. As part of my autocomplete function (this is needed to standardize user input-- don't want the problem of some people typing *UCLA* and others *University of California, Los Angeles*), I need Qualtrics to read a csv file of schools that is currently stored in my Files Library, and that convert that csv into an array. I'm having trouble getting it to read the file to begin with.

I've tried using ajax (still don't really know what it is- I'm bumbling, here). Here is my attempt with ajax in Javascript:

```
    autocomplete: function() {
    var availableTags;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "illinoislas.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php?F=F_8Aek00I0KXkihUN",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(result){
            availableTags = jQuery.csv.toArrays(result);
        }
});
    jQuery(".InputText" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
}
```

As far as I can tell, the ajax request isn't succeeding. The url I provided it is the *View* button of the csv file in my library, and it's obviously not a csv, but I don't know how else to proceed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simple AJAX request on your 'csv' URL

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://illinoislas.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php?F=F_8Aek00I0KXkihUN",
    method: "GET"
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

... and ran into the CORS policy error in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://illinoislas.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php?F=F_8Aek00I0KXkihUN' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served. ... Certain "cross-domain" requests, notably Ajax requests, are forbidden by default by the same-origin security policy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

---

Basically you can't do AJAX requests to external domains unless the server you are calling is designed to return a header saying it's okay. The same applies to iframes (as soon as you try to access the content of the iframe with javascript). It's a browser security mechanism to protect the user.

The easiest fix would be to make a copy of that 'csv' file and host it on the same domain as your page. You can still use AJAX `URL: "./assets/schools.csv"`

Also note, testing your AJAX response with a `console.log(result)` is an easy way to check you have data coming back from the request.

Comment: Hey James, thanks for your response! Although I'm not sure, I believe the csv file is hosted on the same domain as the page. I'm trying to get this all done in Qualtrics, an online survey platform, that is customizable using Javascript. While making my own page with my own domain to do this is not out of the question, I want to exhaust Qualtrics before I do so.

Comment: Ah okay I didn't realise it was hosted on there too. The CORS stuff can still be an issue across sub domains, but first we should figure out if that's the issue. If it is, you should be getting the CORS policy error in your console in your browser dev tools. You should also try the console.log(result) which will print your response in your the console in browser dev tools.

Comment: Also if this is just a static list that you are using for input validation that is the same of each student or whatever, it is probably easier to just make a copy of the csv data and host it in a folder next to your javascript/html files

Comment: I don't think Qualtrics give us enough freedom to store the csv data next to the javascript/html files. The only way I know of interacting with it is including code in what's essentially a html document that is attached to the survey- I don't have access to the directory. Maybe it's the case that I'm getting a CORS policy error even though the files are hosted close to each other in domain space. I wouldn't know, though, because the html file I've been writing to is not a console that gives feedback... This is frustrating. I'm sorry!